# translateX overrides translateY

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make different classes for alignment.

I want to be able to combine it like `class="left bottom"` using the `transform:translate` property.

The problem is that the property is being overridden by each other.

If you have a look at my fiddle and open up the debugger you will notice that `translateX(50%)` has been overridden by `translateY(25%)`. Shouldn't they be combined like `translate(50%,25%)`?

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.left {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.bottom {
  transform: translateY(25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left bottom">
    I should be aligned
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r2LmfqLs

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly correct, because you are changing the `transform` parameter.

You have to nest them:

```
.left.bottom {
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(25%);
}
```

Or combine them to one class:

```
.left-bottom {
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(25%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is only one `transform` **property** but two *values*, so which ever comes last...wins.

You could make one "combined" class...like so.

```
.container {
  background:gray;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
.left {
  transform:translateX(50%);
}
.bottom {
  transform:translateY(25%);
}

.left.bottom {
transform:translateX(50%) translateY(25%);
}
```